# Android Reflection Fails for Annotation

Tags: java, android, annotations

having difficulty getting information about a fields annotation

here is my annotation:

```
public @interface DbField {}
```

here is my class:

```
public class AccountData extends Data {

    @DbField
    public String uidnext;
```

here is my reflection

```
Field f = AccountData.class.getField("uidnext");
Log.d("fcrow", String.format("%s:%b", f.getName(),
                f.getAnnotation(DbField.class) != null));
```

output is:

```
D/fcrow: uidnext:false
```

I'm confused most of what I can find online points to this code working.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/

Comment: I have read this, and am still perplexed as to why my code does not work, is there a specific part of the article that jumped out at you for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your annotation declaration to include a runtime retention policy:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DbField {}
```

If you do not do this, you will get the default retention policy `CLASS`. Its documentation states:

> Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time. This is the default behavior.